# How to perform intersection operation on two datasets in Key-Value store?

Tags: cassandra, redis, couchbase, key-value-store, nosql

Let's say I have 2 datasets, one for rules, and the other for values.

I need to filter the values based on rules.

I am using a Key-Value store (couchbase, cassandra etc.). I can use multi-get to retrieve all the values from one table, and all rules for the other one, and perform validation in a loop.

However I find this is very inefficient. I move massive volume of data (values) over the network, and the client busy working on filtering.

What is the common pattern for finding the intersection between two tables with Key-Value store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind the nosql data model is to write data in a denormalized way so that a table can answer to a precise query. To make an example imagine you have reviews made by customers on shops. You need to know the reviews made by a user on shops and also reviews received by a shop. This would be modeled using two tables

ShopReviews
UserReviews

In the first table you query by shop id in the second by user id but data are written twice and accessed directly using just a key access.

In the same way you should organize values by rules (can't be more precise without knowing what's the relation between them) and so on. One more consideration: newer versions of nosql db supports collections which might help to model 1 to many relations.

HTH, Carlo